# Mysql Lost Routines/Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using MySQL Workbench 5.2.40 CE,I exported database into dump file and i missed to check "Dump Stored Routines",after i dropped it,
After importing this dump routines are lost
How can i restore stored procedures / routines ?

Comment: let me get this straight, you dont have access to old DB cause you have DROP it?

Comment: not exactly a stack question IMO

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, you can restore the database if you have `the backup in any form.` Otherwise you might be out of luck. Similar questions have been asked before here, refer to this [link](https://serverfault.com/a/92670)